# Get data from modal input, calculate then display result in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some working jQuery that grabs the value from an input from which the user enters, and then also grabs a value from a hidden field, the jQuery then performs the necessary calculations and displays the result.

The issue I am having is when I put the fields into a modal, it doesn't work, even when I try and state the modal ID before the input ID.

Can someone help me get this working as needed?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demoModal #qty").keyup(function() {
      totalTP = $("#demoModal #qty").val() * $("#demoModal #price").val() / 100;
      $("#demoModal #totalTP").val(totalTP);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label>Enter your taxable monthly profit</label>
          <input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" />
          <input hidden name="price" id="price" type="hidden" value="19" /><br />

          <label>Deducitble Tax Available</label>
          <input name="totalTP" id="totalTP" type="text" />
          <br>
          <br>

          <form id='fm'>
            <label>HR:</label>
            <select class="first">
              <option disabled selected value="0">Select Plan</option>
              <option value="0">No Plan</option>
              <option value="50">HR Plan</option>
              <option value="100">HR Pro</option>
              <option value="200">HR Pro+</option>
              <option value="400">HR Pro Plan</option>
            </select>
            <label>Accounting:</label>
            <select class="second">
              <option disabled selected value="0">Select Plan</option>
              <option value="0">No Plan</option>
              <option value="50">Accounting Plan</option>
              <option value="100">Accounting Pro</option>
              <option value="200">Accounting Pro+</option>
              <option value="400">Accounting Pro Plan</option>
            </select>
            <label>Graphic Design & Marketing:</label>
            <select class="third">
              <option disabled selected value="0">Select Plan</option>
              <option value="0">No Plan</option>
              <option value="50">Graphic Design Plan</option>
              <option value="100">Graphic Design Pro</option>
              <option value="200">Graphic Design Pro+</option>
              <option value="400">Graphic Design Pro Plan</option>
            </select>

            <input hidden type="text" class="form-control" id="temp" name="temp">
            <input hidden type="text" class="form-control" id="bc" name="bc">
            <input hidden type="text" class="form-control" id="de" name="de">

          </form>

          <br>

          <label>Plan Costs:<div id="total"></div> </label>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1np6eugc/)

Comment: What you mean by "_it doesn't work_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: When inputting e.g. 1000 in the qty field, it should get the value, perform the calculation as the JQuery shows above, then input and spit the result into the totalTP field, yet nothing happens when I input 1000 for e.g... it does work when I take the input fields etc out of the modal @palaѕн

Comment: can u put it to jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, will add link in above

Comment: Are you testing this when modal is open? and you are saying `$("#qty").val()` returned nothing?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1np6eugc/ @Çağrı, yes modal is open and yes, I enter a value in the qty field input but obviously the JQuery is not grabbing the value entered in the input field

Comment: Your demo is working fine: [Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3dcuyLvp/) modal id was incorrect in your js fiddle demo.

Comment: @palaѕн as soon as I save the code from the fiddle,  it dosn't work, even  with the correct jquery version

Comment: At least, it is clear now that there some issue is in your end, as the js fiddle is working fine. Nothing much can be done from here.